# Prove that $\sum_{n≥0} a_k(n)x^n = \frac{1-x}{1- 2x + x^{k+1}}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let k be a fixed positive integer and for all n≥0 let $a_k(n)$ be the number of compositions of n where each part is at most k. Set $a_k(0) = 1$. For instance, if k = 2 then $a_k(1) = 1$, $a_k(2) = 2$, $a_2(3) = 3$, $a_2(4) = 5$ and so on.

Prove that
$$
\sum_{n≥0} a_k(n)x^n = \frac{1-x}{1- 2x + x^{k+1}}
$$

I know that $a_k(n) = C(n-1,k-1)$, so

$\sum_{n≥0}a_k(n)x^n = a_k(0)x^0 + a_k(1)x^1 + ... + a_k(n)x^n$

$= 1*1 + 1*x + C(1, k-1)x^2 + C(2, k-1)x^3 + ... + C(n-1, k-1)x^n$

I'm just not really sure where to go from here or if I'm even going in the right direction.

*I also know that $\sum_{n≥0}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$. Obviously I'm gonna need to use that but I think I just need a push in the right direction.

*I thought about trying to prove this by induction but I'm still a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that $a_k(n)$ *isn't* $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, as you can check just with the values of $a_2(n)$ that you've already computed. Consider a composition of $n$ into parts no larger than $k$: if its last part is $i$, where $1\le i\le k$, the other parts are a composition of $n-i$ into parts no larger than $k$. Conversely, every composition of $n-i$ into parts no larger than $k$ can be extended to one of $n$ by tacking $i$ onto the end. Thus,

$$a_k(n)=a_k(n-1)+a_k(n-2)+\ldots+a_k(n-i)$$

for $n\gt k$. Moreover, $a_k(n)=2^{n-1}$ for $1\le n\le k$, so if we set $a_k(0)=1$ and $a_k(n)=0$ for $n\lt 0$, we have

$$a_k(n)=a_k(n-1)+a_k(n-2)+\ldots+a_k(n-k)+[n=0]\tag{1}$$

for all $n$, where the last term is an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Letting $g_k(x)$ be the generating function for $\langle a_k(n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, we can multiply $(1)$ through by $x^n$ and sum over $n\ge 0$ to get

$$\begin{align*}
g_k(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_k(n-1)x^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}a_k(n-2)x^n+\ldots+\sum_{n\ge 0}a_k(n-k)x^n+1\\
&=xg_k(x)+x^2g_k(x)+\ldots+x^kg_k(x)+1\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now solve for $g_k(x)$:

$$g_k(x)=\frac1{1-x(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{k-1})}\;,$$

and a little algebra will finish the job.

Comment: Oh oops you're right, I think I was wishing so hard for an answer that I made what I had make sense in my head.

Thank you so much! That actually all makes sense now.

Comment: @Karen: You’re welcome!